# Does AdS space-time have global translation symmetry?

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I couldn't find any papers/articles addressing this particular issue. To elucidate, my question is the following,

**Question:** Given the maximally symmetric nature of AdS space-time, we also have that it is homogeneous and isotropic. Does the former imply translation symmetry (globally or locally)?

Either way, since far away from the AdS center, the space is conformally flat, one might expect the exact translation invariance of Minkowski space to re-surface in some form. I am quite confused regarding this. Any relevant literature and/or explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: It has time translation symmetry which acts globally.

Comment: But if I'm not wrong, the homogeneity is in spatial components right ? Shouldn't there be translation symmetry for space too globally ?

Comment: Homogenous and isotropic spaces don’t have a “center”.

Comment: These lectures contain rather a good exposition of AdS in the second chapter - https://sites.krieger.jhu.edu/jared-kaplan/files/2016/05/AdSCFTCourseNotesCurrentPublic.pdf